# How does push notification work?

Tags: android

My exact question is that
is an app listens from the notification
server in android.sevice?
Is this mean that every app has its own
notification server,my phone listens for 
all of those servers?

Comment: Have a look at this https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html.
AFAIK a GCM server is a like a facade for all the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is single server (theoretically, it can be server infrastructure) hosted by your phone manufacturer (Google, Apple etc). If you as a developer wants to send push notification to your app user's phone, you sends it to this server and do not care how when or if it is delivered.